# Calling a function with a variable number of arguments

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
library(plyr)

stack_dataframes <- function(...){
  
  dataframes <- list(...)
  
  for (i in dataframes){
  colnames(i) <- "b"
  }
  
  plyr::rbind.fill(...)  
  # Still has the colnames "a", but I want to stack 
  # all the changed dataframes with colname "b"
}
```

Some sample data and call the function with three parameters

```r
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2))
df2 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2))
df3 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2))

stack_dataframes(df1, df2, df3)
```

But how can I change the `stack_dataframes()`-function so that it will automatically adjust the parameters in `plyr::rbind.fill()` according to the number of data.frames? E.g. if I call `stack_dataframes(df1, df2)` with two data.frames it should also be `plyr::rbind.fill(df1, df2)` etc.

Comment: Do the checks modify the data? If not, can you not just use the `...` notation to pass the arguments from the top-level function to `plyr::rbind.fill()`?

Comment: as @jsavn mentioned just pass the dots to `plyr::rbind.fill`

Comment: yes, the data frames are changed within the function, so I cannot just pass the `...` to the rbind.fill-function.

Comment: if you have a list of data.frames then use `do.call(rbind.fill, dataframes)`

Comment: Sorry, maybe my problem was unclear... I have a list "...", but the problem is, that I change the elements within this list afterwards (see my post above)

Comment: actually you do not change the elements of the list. `for (i in seq_along(dataframes)) colnames(dataframes[[i]])<-"b"` instead

Comment: can't I simply create a new list? If I know that I have (let's say) `length(list(...))` dataframes and that my dataframes are all called `df1`, `df2`..., `df3`? I mean, can I call an object using a string as the name (e.g. "df1")?

Comment: OK, I found a solution: ```list_of_dfs2 <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(list(...))){
    list_of_dfs2[[i]] <- get(paste0("df", i))
  }```